# Testing react components in jest-expo always fails

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, npm, jestjs, expo

I have followed the following tutorial for installing Jest with expo.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/testing-with-jest/

After following this tutorial I encountered these errors:

```
react-native/jest-preset contained different transformIgnorePatterns than expected
 FAIL  __test__/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@unimodules/react-native-adapter' from 'setup.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:230:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/jest-expo/src/preset/setup.js:218:6)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.348s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Now I could install the packace using `npm install @unimodules/react-native-adapter --save-dev`.
But this will result in the following errors

```
The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project.

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expo/src/environment/validate.ts:11:9)
      at Object.require (node_modules/expo/build/Expo.js:278:1)

  console.warn node_modules/expo-react-native-adapter/build/NativeModulesProxy.js:43
    The "ExpoNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that expo-react-native-adapter's native code is linked properly

  console.warn node_modules/expo-constants/build/Constants.js:4
    No native ExponentConstants module found, are you sure the expo-constants's module is linked properly?
```

I have tried solving this by following many google links, I have tried the following :

- Installing just Jest together with Enzyme.
- Deleting all my node modules and reinstalled them.
- Using only yarn